# Tooltip on Preference Assumes Checkbox is Ticked

Tags: discussion, user-interface

In [User Preference](https://stackoverflow.com/users/preferences) page, the tooltip for the "Email chat event reminders, bounty expiration notice, and achievement announcements" seems to assume that it is ticked, even when it is not. This creates confusion as what would happen when I tick on the checkbox.

Currently when I hover over the checkbox, it says "Opt out of Email Delivery". Does that mean that when I tick on that checkbox I will opt-out? I don't think so. See the screenshot below.

[image: Tooltip Screenshot]

I think it should be standardized just like the other two options, for which the tooltips say "New Features" and "Tips & Recommendations" respectively.

Maybe change it to something like "Reminders"?